# Asp.net Performance Issue

Tags: database, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have been working on Asp.net (Classic), where I need to render the lot of data in Telerik - grid.

During loading, its taking too much time. My doubt is which one is causing the impact.

1. Whether the compilation of server side to html controls.
2. DB calls which generate the data.
3. If compilation takes time means, then in MVC apps rendering in datatable also takes time.

Kindly answer me to solve this.

Comment: This is a good question to ask, but there is no way **we** could find out. You are the programmer. Go and find out what's taking so long, so you can fix it.

Comment: I can find out, but my question is whether rendering the html will take time or DB call will take time primarily. How to trace it or any tools to capture it.

Comment: This might be low-tech, but did you put a breakpoint in your code and check how long the db call takes? Which VS version do you use?

Comment: Is there are any specifications which is followed while rendering, eg: table will find the closing tags before it renders.

Answer (score 1):

There's no way *we* can solve your problem, but perhaps we can help you find some tools to solve it yourself.

1. [System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch(v=vs.110).aspx) is your friend.  You can use that to time any of your server side code.
2. Press <kbd>F12</kbd> on your browser (especially if you are using Chrome) and use the diagnostic tools.  There are options in there to show what's going on in the client and how long it takes.

Answer (score 0):

We can only guess, but!

- 99% of the time performance issues are caused by running sql statements inside a loop.

ie

```
for(int i=0;i<100;i++)
{
    var sql = "select * from table where id='" + i + "'";
    var dr = connection.ExecuteCommand(sql);
    //write data out somewhere
}
```

A simple check for this (in classic asp) is just to go through and add

```
Response.Write(DateTime.UtcNow);
```

all over the place. Stopwatch will give you better accuracy, but if we are talking seconds this will be enough.

You are right though in that client side rendering of html can also be slow. Especially if you have complex css or lots of javascript.

Pressing F12 and looking at the loading times in your browser should tell you whether this is a problem.

https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/evaluate-performance/timeline-tool

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem at a previous employer- we had to contact Telerik and get support from them, as the issue was in the Telerik grid. Something else to consider... but I agree with the comments- without more information it's hard to help.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly i recommend to use some Performance Profiler to track the performance problems, there are many tools out there either for The DB or The web applications for example :

[ANTS Performance Profiler](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-performance-profiler/)

---

**Some Notes :**

- The Telerik products have many features but on the other hand have many problems concerning performance (rendering time) and the UX.
- [I would recommend avoiding Telerik, and any other .NET-specific UI tools, entirely. A well-built web interface (client-side browser) shouldn't have hard dependencies on the type of server framework being used (ASP.NET, Python, Ruby).](https://ux.stackexchange.com/a/98194/10628)
- Debug, Debug, And Debug, Debugging can tell you a lot of things about your application.